# Strange sentence structure, the use of "had"

Tags: inversion

> Only through dire circumstance **had** they discovered that he was also the dragon Kotrialstrasz. - *In Warcraft: War of the Ancients #1*

So why is the word "had" put in that position in the sentence or can it be put after "they"?

Thank you.

Comment: It's called **[subject-auxiliary inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb_inversion_in_English)**, and in this case it's use is licensed by the presence of "only through dire circumstances", which is called "introductory negative" (Quirk et al, 1984, Unit 3.24)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Only through dire circumstance had they discovered that he was also the dragon Kotrialstrasz.

The meaning of the sentence:

> They managed to discover that he was also the dragon Kotrialstrasz. But they managed to do that *only through dire circumstance*.

---

1. **They had** discovered a dragon. (Subject - Auxiliary - Verb - Object)
2. **Had they** discovered a dragon? (Auxiliary - Subject - Verb - Object)
3. *Only through dire circumstance* **had they** discovered a dragon (ASVO)
4. **They had** discovered a dragon *only through dire circumstance* (SAVO)

Sentence 1 has the standard word order (**[SAVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb%E2%80%93object)**). **They** is Subject, **had** is an Auxiliary, **discovered** is a Verb, and **dragon** is an Object.

In sentence 2 we have **[Subject-Auxiliary inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion)**, because it's a question.

Sentence 3 is not a question, but it begins with a phrase of "negative meaning": "Only through dire circumstances". This also allows us to invert the word order.

If instead of this phrase we would use a phrase with no negative meaning, it would be better to retain the standard word order (SVO):

> *On Monday morning* they had discovered a dragon. (Subject - Auxiliary - Verb - Object)

"On Monday morning" is an adverbial phrase with a non-negative meaning, so it would look weird with inversion:

> *On Monday morning* had they discovered a dragon. (WRONG!)

If we add "Only", we will make the meaning of the phrase negative, and we'll have to invert the auxiliary verb and the subject:

> *Only on Monday morning* had they discovered a dragon. (OKAY)

But if we move this "negative phrase" from its fronted position, we'll switch back to the standard declarative sentence word order:

> They had discovered a dragon *only on Monday morning*.

---

References:

- Quirk et al., *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language*, Unit 18.24, "Subject-Operator Inversion".

---

Some other examples (*in italics*) of fronted negatives licensing the inversion (**in bold**):

> *Least of all* **is it** possible to discuss this issue at this late hour.
>
> *At no time* **must you** allow this candle to burn out.
>
> *In this way alone* **could he** achieve success.
>
> *Not a single question* **did he** answer during the interrogation.

Comment: +1 But this might be more useful to learners if you gave examples of other fronted negatives which coerce inversion.

Comment: So, how can I understand this sentence? As you said, it is not a question so that can we understand this as normal?

Comment: @vietphi - I've added a short explanation of the sentence to my answer.